# Measuring 32V using ADC of Atmega8

Tags: microcontroller, avr, adc, c

I'm trying to measure the battery voltage of 30V using the ADC of an AVR Atmega8, AVCC is connected to 5V.

I connected a suitable voltage divider: R1 is 270k, R2 is 10k. The result I get is wrong at all, at 30V I get 23V. 
The equation I use is `batteryvoltage = 5*1023/adcReading`.

```
// Read the AD conversion result
unsigned int read_adc(unsigned char adc_input)
{
ADMUX=adc_input|ADC_VREF_TYPE;
// Start the AD conversion
ADCSRA|=0x40;
// Wait for the AD conversion to complete
while ((ADCSRA & 0x10)==0);
ADCSRA|=0x10;
return ADCW;
}
unsigned int adcReading = 0;

adcReading = read_adc(0);
batteryVoltage = 5*1023/adcReading;
```

Comment: Why are you dividing by the adcReading?

Comment: @pjc50 to get the full reading of the battery ?

Comment: adcReading should be numerator, not the denominator. Configured as it is, the result will _decrease_ with increasing voltage.

Comment: @NickJohnson The result is always zero... How also can I modify it to bte the result increase with decreasing voltage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your calculation for the battery voltage is wrong. Assuming `adcReading` varies from 0 to 1023, it should look like this:

```
batteryVoltage = (adcReading * 30) / 1023
```

Note though that denoting voltage like this, with integer volts, will only give you 31 possible readings (0 to 30). A more useful result might be in millivolts:

```
batteryVoltageMillivolts = (adcReading * 30000) / 1023
```

Note that in this case `batteryVoltageMillivolts` will have to be a `long`, not an `int`.

Comment: can you help me with the voltage divider issure please? I think its also affecting..

Comment: What voltage divider issue? You didn't specify one in the question.

Comment: I have specified R1 = 50k, R2=10k, this gives 5V at 30V, but still the output is wrong using your equations above.

Comment: You said R1=270k above! What's the actual reading at the adc input pin with a voltmeter?

Comment: You want to ensure that the divider allows some "overflow" - if you want to measure 32V but your ADC input voltage is 5V (ie max) at 30V you will have a problem!

Comment: @Andrew yea I would like to provide some overflow and also prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

@Mahmoud - depending on the resolution of your ADC (10 bit, 12 bit?) I'd be minded to divide by 10 using your resistor divider - so 32V == 3.2V at the ADC

This gives a possible range of 50V == 5.0V at the ADC therefore no overloading of the input.

For the 10 bit ADC this then gives you a resolution of 0.049V for a 50V input

If you need a bit more accuracy, divide to 35V == 5.0V at the input which gives you a resolution of 0.034V

Comment: its 10bit of the AVR Atmega8